# How can I download and install Numpy and Pandapower?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, gui, pip

How can I Download and install numpy and pandapower on the RASPBIAN JESSIE LITE Minimal image based on Debian Jessie? the one without the GUI. And how can I download and install Pip and miniconda on it as well?

Answer (score -1):

I just set this up today. Links to directions for installing mini-anaconda. When I installed TF it installed Numpy, not sure about pandapower?

Install Mini Anaconda

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b

Install TensorFlow with numpy

https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi